# Method does not catch firestore timeout error

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I have following code where I cannot catch Firestore timeout error when internet is slow. It just returns empty array.

```
static getEspeciallyProducts() {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            const db = Firebase.firestore(),
                products = [],
                activeRef = await db.collection("products")
                    .orderBy("id")
                    .withConverter(ProductConverter)
                    .get();
            for (let doc of activeRef.docs) {
                const data = doc.data();
                if (_.isObject(data))
                    products.push(data);
            }
            resolve(products);
        } catch (error) {
            reject(error);
        }
    });
}
```

However, my another method catches an error:

```
static getProductById(id) {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            const docRef = Firebase.firestore().collection("products").doc(id),
                doc = await docRef.withConverter(ProductConverter).get();
            if (doc.exists)
                resolve(doc.data());
            else
                resolve(null);
        } catch (error) {
            reject(error);
        }            
    });
}
```

Comment: Would you like to share the specific error that you get in the second case?

Comment: In the second case I catch firebase timeout error. I need it to show Refresh button so user can refresh the screen.

Comment: So the second query didn't throw an exception at all, and it behaves like I describe in my answer?  You can certainly process a timeout like that, but it doesn't "stop" the query.

Comment: In the second method I get following error: 'Failed to get document because the client is offline.' and it catches an error.

Comment: In that case, the failure is specifically saying that the specific document is not in the local cache.  For the first example, since it's a query, it's not looking for a specific document, rather, any document that happens to match.  Since your local cache has no matching documents, you get an empty array.  If you disagree with this behavior, feel free to file an issue with Firebase support directly.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Answer (score 0):

Firestore doesn't throw errors in the event that the internet connection is slow or down.  It either:

1. Silently retries until the connection is available, or
2. Gives up and falls back to the local persistence layer.

If it does #2, you will see a message in the console log about that.  But the code making a query will not just fail.  Failure are only given for errors that cannot be recovered, such as security rule violations and exceeded limits.

If you want code to fail in the event of a network problem, consider using the [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/use-rest-api) instead.